# How to find if a column is computed column or not using apache metamodel?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, apache-metamodel

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Java Apache metamodel.
In SQL Server, I can find if a tables's column is computed or not using the following query:-

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE is_computed = 1
AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')
```

But I need to find if the column is computed or not in my code in Java using apache metamodel.

Is there any possible way to find it?

Thanks!